# JavaScript: Is it is possible to preload external sites?

Tags: javascript, performance, preload, prefetch

I couldn't find the answer to this particular question on Stack Overflow. Not particularly looking for an implementation (unless it happens to exist already), but ...

Say I have an intranet application, which loads very quickly. This has links to a number of external sites, all of which we can assume load very slowly. The user will definitely visit all of the links on the page, and will definitely not do that straight away (we don't *know*, but it's unlikely they'll open a link within the first ten seconds of the page loading).

I would like to start these external links downloading, without opening a new window/tab, before they've clicked on a link? I've noticed http://instantclick.io/ has such an ability, but specifically warns against loading external sites (or rather, sites with different CSS/JS files)

Anyhoo, is it possible to start caching an external site with JS (or anything else for that matter)?  Would it be possible, say, to preload the HTML page but *not* any associated CSS/JS files to fit the problem instantclick.io mentions?  Even if it's **one** element of an external site that could be pre-emptively downloaded, that would be a useful gain ...

Comment: You probably can create iframe with null size, and assign its srс to your site. It will cause to load/render page and some static resources from it will be cached. However: it's not a cache of _whole_ page. As for me, it's generally bad idea.

Comment: Tommi - out of interest, why would you say it's a bad idea?

Comment: Asssuming you have 20 links to 20 pages, and you start preload of each at once. This is huge load for CPU, RAM and network. It's similar to open 20 separated tabs in browser. More, user is probably will never open whole batch of 20 links, so you tell user's PC to do big and (probably) useless job. And one more: second time when user opens your page, preload starts again. But all useful job (cache of static css, js, images) already done in previous page opening.

Comment: SO said that comment is too long, so here is trail: So, for second time this big job is definetely useless. Finally, you can't save your preload complete flag to cookie, because user can clear cache manually.

Comment: Two very good points. Can be certain that the user will open most, if not all, of the links - but you're right, generally speaking it would be a stupid idea :) Particularly if it loads everything twice, which kinda defeats the point of making things faster ... needs a great deal of thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

load all the external files in iframes i.e.

```
<div style="display:none;">
<iframe name="i2" src="www.xyz.com"></iframe>
<iframe name="i3" src="www.xyzsf.com"></iframe>
<iframe name="i1" src="www.xysfz.com"></iframe>
...
</div>
```

Comment: why -1 for this answer ?

Comment: Without specifying a reason doing a -1 makes no sense . . . crazy people out there.

Comment: Indeed. Even more, second answer has -1 as well, while both answers makes perfect sence.

Comment: +1ed both of ya, I'd agree ... the -1 makes no sense whatsoever! :)

Thanks Ashish - I think you might be on to something there

Comment: This technique is bad for SEO.